# How to rearrange each image patch into number of column vector

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am working on a project where i have used a image whose size is (512x512)then i have divided the whole image by 8 so that there will be 64x64 block then i have to rearrange each 8x8 image patch into a single column so that new size would be 
64x4069. unable to understand how to do it.please help.
Here is my code

enter code here

```
a=imread('lena.png');
b=double(a);
[r,c]=size(b);
bl=8;
br=r/bl;
bc=r/bl;
```

It will arrange in such a order that first column would be image patch of (1:8,1:8)next column would be(9:16,9:16)likewise.

Comment: have you tried [`im2col`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) ?

Comment: @santhan salai i have to implement without inbuilt function

Comment: You have to include that in your question. is `mat2cell`, `permute` or `reshape`  allowed?

Comment: because they don't do it directly but it may be a vectorized approach for your loops

Comment: @ santhan salai reshape is allowed.

Comment: @SanthanSalai i have to implement using for loop.

Comment: Edited my answer. Rectified some mistakes as well as added loopy approach as per your request. check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [`reshape`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) is allowed, [`permute`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/permute.html) is definitely allowed.

Assuming both the original and block sub-matrix are square matrices

Here is one approach

```
out = permute(reshape(A,blSz,size(A,1)/blSz,blSz,[]),[1 3 2 4]);
out = reshape(out,size(out,1)*size(out,1),[]);
```

**Sample inputs:**

```
A = randi(50,8);    %// Change it with your original `512x512` matrix
blSz = 2;           %// Change it to 8 for your problem
```

**Results:**

```
>> A

A =

31    17    18    10    33    31    43    16
20    40    31    15    34    23    42     6
46    24    10     5    32    23    13    47
 1     2    37    29    48    34    31    33
24     9    13    35    11    39    30    24
22    37    46    28    36    18    28    32
24    24    14    22    12    34    44    28
39     8    39    33     6    21    14    33

>> out

out =

31    46    24    24    18    10    13    14    33    32    11    12    43    13    30    44
20     1    22    39    31    37    46    39    34    48    36     6    42    31    28    14
17    24     9    24    10     5    35    22    31    23    39    34    16    47    24    28
40     2    37     8    15    29    28    33    23    34    18    21     6    33    32    33
```

**Using loops as OP requested**

```
A = randi(50,8);
blSz = 2;
nBl = size(A,1)/2;

out = zeros(size(reshape(A,blSz*blSz,[])));
count = 1;
for ii = 1:nBl
    for jj= 1:nBl
        block = A((jj-1)*blSz + 1:(jj-1)*blSz + blSz, (ii-1)*blSz + 1:(ii-1)*blSz + blSz);
        out(:,count) = block(:);
        count = count + 1;
    end
end
```

Gives the same result as above!

Alternative for `im2col` using vectorized approach

```
newOut = mat2cell(reshape(out,blSz,[]),blSz,repmat(blSz,size(out,2),1));
newOut = cell2mat(reshape(newOut,nBl,[]));
```

Comment: @P.Bisoyi if you found this answer helpful, Consider marking it as accepted. This can be done by clicking the checkmark below the up and down arrows to the left of my answer

Comment: can you help me how to get back 512x512 size from 64x4069 size using for loop.

Comment: @P.Bisoyi Let me add the solution

Comment: @P.Bisoyi added vectorized approach instead. i find it difficult implementing using for loop, if you want to do that in for loop alone, please post it explicitly as a new question stating you want to replicate `col2im` using for loop

Comment: here in the program the output size is 64x4096 but i want new size would be 48x4096,how to remove last 16 rows.

Comment: @P.Bisoyi I thought you wanted to replicate `im2col`. If you do it with `im2col` you would end up with `64x4096` only. If you just wanted to remove last 16 rows, then do `out(end-15:end,:) = []` this will remove last 16 rows from the already produced output.